# Linux Command to view the users

Tags: linux

I have tried many sites where only possibility to view the users present in my linux CentOS is to view the /etc/passwd file. What are the commands to view the users who are present in CentOS except "cat /etc/passwd" ?

Comment: What's wrong with getting the answer from /etc/passwd? It's always available, always readable, and easy to parse.

Comment: If for some actual reason you do not want to read /etc/passwd, you can use the command, "getent passwd" which gives the same information

Comment: @Malt: `/etc/passwd` is not always complete - user information could also come from NIS, LDAP and so on...

Comment: What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve by listing the users?

Comment: @thkala These are the questions that I am facing while teaching to the students. I used to tell them that it is one of the best way. But now I am getting a lot of answers..Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you tried lastlog ?

This should list all the users and when they last logged in - including never:

```
 lastlog |more
      1 Username         Port     From             Latest
      2 root                                       **Never logged in**
      3 daemon                                     **Never logged in**
      4 bin                                        **Never logged in**
      5 sys                                        **Never logged in**
      6 sync                                       **Never logged in**
      7 games                                      **Never logged in**
      8 man                                        **Never logged in**
      9 lp                                         **Never logged in**
     10 mail                                       **Never logged in**
```

Comment: Its cool vahid :) Thanks

Comment: indeed cos you could parse out active users rather than users that are system users etc... no worries

Answer (score 1):

You can use `getent passwd`:

```
$getent passwd | cut -d: -f1 
at
avahi
beagleindex
bin
daemon
dnsmasq
festival
ftp
games
gdm
git-daemon
haldaemon
icecream
lighttpd
```

Answer (score 0):

These commands still read `/etc/passwd` but only show usernames. At least they're different from `cat /etc/passwd`.

```
awk -F: '{ print $1 }' /etc/passwd
cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd
sed 's|:.*||' /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you try

```
cd /users/

ls
```

Directory names will be the users.

Comment: There is no folder named /users. At least not on the Red Hat release I'm using. Do you mean /home?

Comment: Yes there is separate directory for each user you create.

I would say create a new user

    "useradd newuser"

and search the directory newuser, you will know where your user directories are saved.

Comment: Ok. Is your HOME variable in useradd set to /users? Perform "cat /etc/default/useradd" to see the value of HOME. My HOME variable in useradd is set to /home. If I perform "useradd newuser" it doesn't create the folder /users/newuser it creates the folder /home/newuser.

Comment: yes then your users directory is under home. Go to home location cd /home and do "ls"

Comment: Yes I know my users directory is /home.
I commented because I think your answer is misleading since /home is the default users directory. I suggest you clarify your answer.

Comment: @user1766169 It's not at all misleading. Not for everyone /home is default users directory. If you use FEDORA then you will see default directory is /users/. I suggest to see the HOME variable in useradd.

Comment: But the question is about CentOS and not Fedora.

Comment: I dont think it as a misleading man. Its cool that you guys provided more solution for viewing the users. Thanks @user1766169